# Read configuration file using only unmanaged C++

Tags: c++, xml, xpath, configuration, app-config

I have an unmanaged Visual C++ project. I need to use a section defined in app configuration file without using any managed assembly.

Is there a library that comes with Visual Studio 2010 installation that can be used for this purpose?

If no such library comes with Visual Studio 2010, I suppose I will have to use a library that supports reading of XML files into memory and performing an XPath query. Which stable libraries support XML and XPath operations?

Comment: regarding the last part of your question, see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5611149/c-library-for-storing-settings-in-xml

Comment: @Wimmel: That is acceptable. Would you post that as an answer so I can accept it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

See [C++ library for storing settings in XML](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5611149/c-library-for-storing-settings-in-xml) for libraries which can read settings in XML files.

If you want something which comes with MSVC, I think the closest you get is using MSXML via a COM interface. But you will need to install the msxml redist on the target machine if it is not already installed. Maybe take a look at [these 6 posts](http://blogs.microsoft.co.il/blogs/davids/archive/2008/12/27/msxml-in-c-but-as-elegant-as-in-c-part-6.aspx).

Answer (score 0):

Do you mean the conventional windows config file (ini)? Libconfig might be helpful, http://gnuwin32.sourceforge.net/packages/libconfig.htm